# pointer to structure not returning a string

Tags: c, pointers, structure, instance-variables

Here's a code i wrote to print out a string from a structure using a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 struct xenon
{
    int size1;
    int marks[10];
    char *w;
    struct xenon *p;
} x1,x2;

main()
{
    x1.size1=10;
    x2.size1=6;
    printf("%d\n",x1.size1);
    printf("%d\n",x2.size1);
    (*p).w="my word";

    printf("%s\n",(*p).w);
    printf("%s\n",x1.w);
}
```

now i get an error saying i haven't declared the variable p in function main. But that should also be the case when i declare

```
x1.w="my word";
printf("%s",x1.w);
```

I also tried declaring the pointer variable just outside the structure and it still wont compile.
Is something wrong with how i declared a pointer to the structure? or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Well, you have defined x1 and x2. So you have x1.p and x2.p but they are not initialized in your code. You could set, for example, x1.p = &x2;

Comment: `x1` and `x2` are global variables, so they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compile-time error is occurring because p is a member of the structure, not a variable in scope. So refer to it as such, just as you've referred to its siblings.

```
(*x1.p).w="my word";

printf("%s\n",(*x1.p).w);
```

Once you fix that, you'll encounter the run-time error that Steger mentioned in the comment above. You could assign x1.p to &x2. But if you're trying to create a linked list, it would be more common that you would want to assign x1.p to a dynamically allocated structure.

Comment: You need to make `x1.p` point to valid memory before dereferencing it

Comment: Yes, and that's mentioned in the second paragraph above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining :)

Comment: however, i did not understand your point about linked lists...would you mind explaining it again?

Comment: One reason for a structure to include a pointer to another instance of the same type is to create a linked list - a linear collection of elements which may be allocated independently and not necessarily adjacent in memory, with a length determined at runtime. I was speculating that might have been your intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
(*p).w="my word";
```

p is a member of the structure. You have not declared any pointer variable to that structure. You need to declare the struct variable as below.

```
struct xenon
{
    int size1;
    int marks[10];
    char *w;
} x1,x2 *p;
```

Here memory for `x1` and `x2` is already allocated, so you can use it directly. But before using `p` either you need to allocate memory or you need to assign address of another struct variable.

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct xenon);
```

or

```
p = &x1;
```

You can assign string literals directly by `p->w="my word"` or else you can allocate memory for that and copy the string like below.

```
p->w = malloc(strlen("my word") + 1);
strcpy(p->w, "my word")
```

Comment: i understood your point, but then how would you assign the string to the char *w?...as in, can you give the specific code?